# ASP.NET MVC website error invoking external WCF Service via NuGet compiled component

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 website that is calling an external WCF service in order to retrieve some data and dynamically render a page.

The call to the WCF service is from within a component (C# class library) that has been added to the website project as a NuGet package (via an internal repository as package source).

When the website is deployed to the server, the call to the WCF service fails with the following error:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: GetCompanyInformation: There was no endpoint listening at https://[domain]/CompanyInformationService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

When the same WCF service call is made from a different website where the same component making the call has been added to the website project as a project reference, and not a NuGet package, the above error does not occur, and the site is able to successfully integrate with service to retrieve data.

I have tried manually replacing the dll for the component in the bin folder for the failing website with that from the website where the service call does not fail, and following this the above error does not occur.

Is there an explanation as to why an external service call from the same class library component will fail with the above error when that component has been added to the project as a NuGet package, but works successfully when the component has been added to the project as a project reference?

Comment: Are you sure that both dll are the same....did you inspect them using a tool like IlSpy ?

Comment: Well, your comment prompted me to take a closer look at the decompiled code - I discovered some #if DEBUG code which created a new web proxy with dummy credentials, for purposes of local development ... I then found that the msbuild file used to create the NuGet package was configured for Debug instead of Release so this code stayed in the dll when published as a NuGet package, which then caused the above error! Thanks a lot for setting me on the right path :)

Comment: I am glad to help you...I always keep IlSpy on my Documents just in case that something like that happens...In your case you just need to publish the `release` version of your assembly to nugget, instead of the `debug` one I think...btw: http://ilspy.net/